# How to disable SharePoint 2013 alerts using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, csom, alerts

Using CSOM, I am able to retrieve the collection of alerts for a SharePoint Online site and disable each alert using the following code:

```
                    context.Load(context.Web.Alerts,
                        collection => collection.Include(
                            alert => alert.ID,
                            alert => alert.Status));
                    context.ExecuteQueryWithRetry();

                    foreach (SP.Alert alert in context.Web.Alerts)
                    {
                        if (alert.Status == AlertStatus.On)
                        {
                            context.Load(alert);
                            alert.Status = AlertStatus.Off;
                            alert.UpdateAlert();
                        }
                    }
                    context.ExecuteQueryWithRetry();
```

This doesn't work for SharePoint 2013 though. I get the error: "Field or property 'Alerts' does not exist". Can this be done with CSOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same question as [How to disable SharePoint 2013 alerts using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286758/how-to-disable-sharepoint-2013-alerts-using-csom/286776#286776)

SharePoint 2013 On-Premise CSOM Web object didn't support Alerts property.

Please use SharePoint Server Object Model below instead:

```
        using (SPSite site=new SPSite("http://sp/sites/MyDev"))
        {
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPAlertCollection alerts = web.Alerts;
            foreach (SPAlert alert in alerts)
            {
                alert.Status = SPAlertStatus.Off;
                alert.Update();
                web.Update();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, as SharePoint 2013 On-Premise CSOM didn't support Alerts https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ced50f4b-6d33-4a17-9230-ae42c617e5ae/is-it-possible-to-control-alerts-through-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment